# Google a word in Vim and display content of first result

Tags: vim, lynx

Is there a mapping to Google the marked word in Vim and display the first result (NOT the search result)?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
nmap <c-l> :ConqueTerm lynx -accept-all-cookies 
  -nopause 'google.com/search?q="something"'<cr>10<down>'
```

Obviously, `10<down>` won't work. Also, `"something"` should be replaced by marked word.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This is the line:

`vnoremap <leader>go :<c-u>exec "!lynx -accept-all-cookies -nopause -cmd_script=~/.vim/lynx_script/lynx_google 'google.com/search?q=" . @* . "'"<cr>`

Vim must be compiled with `+x11` for register `@*` to work.

`<c-u>` will clear the leading `'<,'>` of visual mapping.

The cmd_script of lynx is simply `key Down Arrow` followed by `key ^J` for enter.